# Why is this question about Unix shell scripting considered "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, off-topic

I noticed that [a question about shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532817/difference-bwteen-sudo-su-and-sudo-u-root) was closed as "off-topic", but I don't understand the reason for this decision. Is it true that certain questions about shell scripting (such as this one) are considered "off-topic"? To me, it seems counter-intuitive for this question to be identified as "off-topic". Can this specific closing reason be justified, or should the question be reopened?

As far as I know, questions about shell scripting or Unix commands are considered on-topic on Stack Overflow. Is there some exception to this rule that I'm unaware of?

Comment: this looks like a question about the linux environment rather than about shell scripting

Comment: @JanDvorak In that case, would the question be more relevant on Superuser than Stack Overflow?

Comment: I would say, [unix.se]

Comment: It's too old to migrate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "... were it a new question", I add

Comment: Looks pretty valid to me.

Comment: @JoeTatavaran Unfortunately, it appears that the question has already been deleted. :(

Answer (score 4):

It's not a programming question. Well, it could easily be one, all they have to do is talk about including it in a shell script and give a snippet.

But in it's current form it's really an end user question. Yes, end user -- most Linux users don't consider `sudo` and whatnot to be programming.

Maybe if it was asked now it could have been migrated to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (or maybe Super User), but it's 2 years old, can't be migrated.

Comment: The "anti-migration rule" seems to be working to our disadvantage here. I wish it were somehow possible to migrate this question to the Superuser or Unix Stack Exchange site, since the question and its answers are still useful and not obsolete.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Meh. It's old, it's answered, why does it matter?

Comment: Because I'm afraid that the question will be deleted in the future(resulting in a loss of knowledge)  instead of being migrated to the correct site. Is there any chance that the question's answer will survive instead of being deleted?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Upvoted. Has answer. Answer upvoted. Clocks out on all three counts. Nope, no deletion

Comment: @Manishearth grossly offtopic -> broken window -> possibility of deletion nontrivial.

Comment: @Rosinante Not grossly off topic, though.

Comment: @Rosinante Why do you think that particular question is "grossly offtopic"?

Comment: It is fundamentally a question about how the sudo facility works. Any programming or scripting issues are incidental.

Comment: @Rosinante So, if someone pasted two bash snippet and asked y u no work (with a clear display of effort, yada yada), that's still off topic? That makes almost all bash questions off topic. Most questions on SO on other languages are like this.

Comment: @AndersonGreen While I disagree with the anti-migration rule, this isn't a good example: there are plenty of similar questions with good answers on [su] and [unix.se] already, there would be no point in migrating this one. Its deletion is no loss.

Comment: personally, I think there's a clear line between the scripting language (iteration, conditionals, variables) and the operating system commands that people invoke with it.